# Script generating BC30205: End of statement expected. compiler error

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am trying to alter an asp.net 2.0 script to dynamically gather values from a database based on a URL variable rather than have multiple versions of the script each with their own hard-coded values (which was how it was designed to operate).

The error is this:

```
Line 51:     Private MSG_FROM As String = "valuehere"
Line 52:     Private MSG_FROM_NAME As String = "valuehere"
Line 53:     Private MSG_SUBJECT As String = "<%# forms.FieldValue("MSG_SUBJECT", Container) %>"
Line 54:     Private MSG_BODY As String = "valuehere"
```

It is the line 53 which is the problem, which is the only variable for this test run that I set to obtain a database value. The database connection is fine and the script operates fine if the value is hard-coded.

Could anyone give me an insight as to what the problem is? MSDN states that I must insert a line terminator. I tried a `/r/n` and `Environment.NewLine` after the second quotation mark to no avail.

This is not really a language I understand, but I am hoping this is something very basic I need to enter.

Thanks,
Ben

---

Some additional information as per the responses:

MSG_SUBJECT is a call to the db cell with that name. The value is plain text to dictate the subject line of the email it will generate. Both solutions here got the script to operate, but mistook the first sent the email with a subject of <%# forms.FieldValue("MSG_SUBJECT", Container) %> and the second with <%# forms.FieldValue('MSG_SUBJECT', Container) %> therefore not recognising it as referencing the db table cell, but as the variable itself. Normally within the code it would say rivate MSG_SUBJECT As String = "Your completed form is attached" and the next variable would follow on the line below, i.e. address to be sent to, sent from. But really, there is little more to the code. The entire script is run server-side. While I could contain these variables within the posting form page and this would work, it is not a solution I want, as the script can also receive FDF data submitted from an acroform which has used the URL submit to facility, therefore in this mode these message variables must be included within the sever-side script. As you said, I really don't know myself whether this is even possible, it is just a punt as keeping the variables within a db is far easier to administrate and deploy new forms than having multiple versions of the script with hard-coded variables. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: To get a better advice you have to show more code. I can't see here any database call. `MSG_SUBJECT` is just a variable which gets a string literal assigned. The content of the string looks like ASP.NET server tag.

Answer (score 1):

Its a syntax error, you have to escape the `"` chars in your string by doubling them like this:

```
Private MSG_SUBJECT As String _
    = "<%# forms.FieldValue(""MSG_SUBJECT"", Container) %>"
```

But i think that won't solve your real problem.
You have to write the `<%#` tag in the aspx form page not in code.
What are you doing with `MSG_SUBJECT`?

Comment: to be honest it is code generated by dreamweaver to call the MSG_SUBJECT database cell contents for whatever record has been selected based on the input url variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
 "<%# forms.FieldValue("MSG_SUBJECT", Container) %>"
```

to this:  `"<%# forms.FieldValue('MSG_SUBJECT', Container) %>"`

The double quotes around MSG_Subject are probably making it think the first quote is the end of the string.

I have a feeling the way you are trying to do this really won't work though as you cannot bind things to variables in this way. <%%> are used in the htm side of the page, but your variables look serverside?

Maybe show some more of your code.

**UPDATE**

This will probably help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090(v=vs.100).aspx

By the sound of it all you need to do is get a subject from a database based on an ID of some kind? Then assign it to a variable?

Comment: That is what I though would happen..
Can you explain again exactly what you are trying to acomplish?

Comment: The quotation marks around this code are required and were there by default in the script. Within them, with the example of the subject line, I would just enter some text. The code within those outer quotation marks is what dreamweaver gave me in order to call that text from the DB cell. The ID for the row is configured as a URL variable, which will work for all input types.